# How can I disappear "button" element in react?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./index.scss";

    export const LotteryForm = () => {
      const [text, setText] = useState("Enter your email address");

      function isSubmit() {
        setText("Thank you!" + `  ${email}`);
        // const btnEl = document.getElementsByName("button");
        // btnEl.style.display = "none";
      }


      return (
        <div>
          <button className="lottery__submit submit" 
            onClick={() => { isSubmit() }}>
            Submit email
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Hello. I'm currently studying React (it's day2...). What I want to do here is when a user hits a button to submit its email address, disappear the button element and only display "Thank you" with the submitted email address. I tried selecting a button element and changed its display property to "none" but it didn't work. Can anyone tell me how can I disappear the button element after submission?

Comment: This is to fix your particular case, but you are using [`getElementsByName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) which "returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name (the value of the name attribute), as an HTMLCollection object." So you need to change that to `getElementsByTagName`, and select the first item of the array with `[0]`: `document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]`. As you learn you'll find better methods to handle this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can an use a state to track the submitted status of the form and [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to only render the button when it has not been submitted:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./index.scss";

export const LotteryForm = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("Enter your email address");
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);

  function isSubmit() {
    setText("Thank you!" + `  ${email}`);
    setIsSubmitted(true);
  }


  return (
    <div>
      {!isSubmitted && 
        <button
          className="lottery__submit submit"
          onClick={isSubmit()}
        >
          Submit email
        </button>
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jgys7z) in action.

Avoid using DOM manipulation to manipulate elements.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an ID for the button:

```
<button id="submitButton" ... />
```

then you do the same as you did

```
const btnEl = document.getElementById("submitButton");
btnEl.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: thank you for the reply! could you tell me why if I set Id works in this case? why get getElementsByName("button") doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but I think you haven't used the name tag, test using the attribute name="button" in your button tag

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style of a jsx element with `style={}`

```
function example() {
  let buttonStyle = {};
  if (/*hidden*/) {
    buttonStyle.display = "hidden";
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <button
        style={buttonStyle}
        className="lottery__submit submit"
        onClick={() => {
          isSubmit();
        }}
      >
        Submit email
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, best would be to capture if the button is visible using state (it is a state that the button is there or not)...

```js
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import "./index.scss";

    export const LotteryForm = () => {
      const [text, setText] = useState("Enter your email address");
      const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

      function isSubmit() {
        setText("Thank you!" + `  ${email}`);
        setVisible(false);
      }


      return (
        <div>
          {visible && 
           ( <button
                 className="lottery__submit submit"
                 onClick={isSubmit}
             >
                 Submit email
             </button>
           ) }
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Now I think to use another state is better, like your example. Arigato Marek!